# vue.js + element-ui form validation rules in dialog

Tags: vue.js, element-ui

I'm using vue.js(4.3.1) and element-ui.
I would like to define the validation rules of my form in dialog.

**eg:**

https://codepen.io/xmcx/pen/XWmMXKp

**Code**

```
<script src="//unpkg.com/vue/dist/vue.js"></script>
<script src="//unpkg.com/element-ui@2.13.1/lib/index.js"></script>
<div id="app">
    <template>
        <div>
            <div class="top-5">
                <el-row>
                    <el-button class="search-btn" type="primary" @click="initOperationData({},'new')">New</el-button>
                </el-row>
            </div>
            <div id="dt" class="top-5">
                <el-table :data="dataList" stripe border highlight-current-row show-overflow-tooltip>
                    <el-table-column label="Name" prop="name" header-align="center" align="center"></el-table-column>
                    <el-table-column label="Age" prop="age" header-align="center" align="center"></el-table-column>
                    <el-table-column label="Gender" prop="gender" header-align="center" align="center">
                        <template slot-scope="scope">{{genderConverter(scope.row.gender)}}</template>
                    </el-table-column>
                    <el-table-column label="State" prop="state" header-align="center" align="center">
                        <template slot-scope="scope">{{stateConverter(scope.row.state)}}</template>
                    </el-table-column>
                    <el-table-column label="Operation" width="144px" fixed="right" header-align="center" align="center">
                        <template slot-scope="scope">
                            <el-row>
                                <el-button @click="initOperationData(scope.row, 'edit')" type="text" size="small">Edit
              </el-button>
                            </el-row>
                        </template>
                    </el-table-column>
                </el-table>
            </div>
            <div class="dialog">
                <el-dialog :title="operationConverter(operation) + 'User'" :visible.sync="operationDialogVisible"
                 width="400px" modal :close-on-press-escape="false" :close-on-click-modal="false"
                 @closed="dialogClosed('operationData')">
                    <el-form :model="operationData" ref="operationData" :rules="rules" label-width="80px">
                        <el-form-item label="Name" prop="name">
                            <el-input v-model="operationData.name" placeholder="please enter name" clearable/>
                        </el-form-item>
                        <el-form-item label="Age" prop="age">
                            <el-input v-model="operationData.age" placeholder="please enter age" clearable/>
                        </el-form-item>
                        <el-form-item label="Gender" prop="gender">
                            <el-select v-model="operationData.gender" placeholder="please choice gender" filterable clearable>
                                <el-option v-for="item in genderList" :key="item.value" :label="item.label"
                         :value="item.value"/>
                            </el-select>
                        </el-form-item>
                        <el-form-item label="State" prop="state">
                            <el-select v-model="operationData.state" placeholder="please choice state" filterable clearable>
                                <el-option v-for="item in stateList" :key="item.value" :label="item.label"
                         :value="item.value"/>
                            </el-select>
                        </el-form-item>
                    </el-form>
                    <span slot="footer" class="dialog-footer">
                        <el-button type="primary" @click="save('operationData')">Save</el-button>
                        <el-button @click="operationDialogVisible = false">Close</el-button>
                    </span>
                </el-dialog>
            </div>
        </div>
    </template>
</div>

var Main = {
  data () {
    return {
      operationList: Object.freeze([
        {value: 'new', label: 'New'},
        {value: 'edit', label: 'Edit'}
      ]),
      stateList: Object.freeze([
        {value: 'enabled', label: 'Enabled'},
        {value: 'disabled', label: 'Disabled'}
      ]),
      genderList: Object.freeze([
        {value: 'male', label: 'Male'},
        {value: 'female', label: 'Female'}
      ]),
      dataList: [
        {name: 'Peter', age: undefined, state: 'enabled', gender: 'male'},
        {name: 'Rocky', age: null, state: 'enabled', gender: 'male'},
        {name: 'Bill', state: 'enabled', gender: 'male'},
        {name: 'Alice', state: undefined, age: 12, gender: 'female'},
        {name: 'Amy', state: null, age: 12, gender: 'female'},
        {name: 'Lucy', age: 12, gender: 'female'}
      ],
      total: 2,
      operationData: {},
      operation: null,
      operationDialogVisible: false,
      rules: {
        name: [
          {required: true, message: 'Name is required', trigger: 'change'},
          {required: true, message: 'Name is required', trigger: 'clear'}
        ],
        age: [
          {required: true, message: 'Age is required', trigger: 'change'},
          {required: true, message: 'Age is required', trigger: 'clear'}
        ],
        state: [
          {required: true, message: 'State is required', trigger: 'change'},
          {required: true, message: 'State is required', trigger: 'clear'}
        ],
        gender: [
          {required: true, message: 'Gender is required', trigger: 'change'},
          {required: true, message: 'Gender is required', trigger: 'clear'}
        ]
      }
    }
  },
  methods: {
    initOperationData (data, operation) {
      this.operationData = JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(data))
      this.operation = operation
      this.operationDialogVisible = true
    },
    save (formName) {
      this.$refs[formName].validate((valid) => {
        if (!valid) {
          return false
        } else {
          this.$message({showClose: true, message: 'Save success', type: 'success'})
        }
      })
    },
    dialogClosed (formName) {
      this.operation = null
      this.resetFields(formName)
    },
    resetFields (formName) {
      this.$refs[formName].resetFields()
    },
    operationConverter (value) {
      for (let item of this.operationList) {
        if (value === item.value) return item.label
      }
      return null
    },
    stateConverter (value) {
      for (let item of this.stateList) {
        if (value === item.value) return item.label
      }
      return null
    },
    genderConverter (value) {
      for (let item of this.genderList) {
        if (value === item.value) return item.label
      }
      return null
    }
  }
    }
var Ctor = Vue.extend(Main)
new Ctor().$mount('#app')
```

**Problem**

If I operate in the following order, there will be verification failure message in the dialog(I hope it will not appear):

order-1: Edit -> Close -> New(or edit) ...

If I operate in the following order, it's ok:

order-2: New -> Close -> New(or edit) ...

**Note**

Before operating in the order of order-1 or order-2, please refresh the page.

Comment: Sorry that i couldn't understand your specific problem, so which Operation was an issue that not working for you?

Comment: I updated my question. I mean, when I operate through the order of order-1, the dialog will show the message of verification failure just after it is displayed, instead of one of the operations.

Answer (score 0):

```
    initOperationData (data, operation) {
      this.operationData = JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(data))
      this.operation = operation
      this.operationDialogVisible = true
      this.$nextTick(() => {
        this.$refs['operationData'].clearValidate()
      })
    },
```

Using `clearValidate`